"Assert function" does not change type
I'm trying to make a package like zod for npm but when parsing it it doesn't update the previous type:
function isString(val: unknown): asserts val is string {
  if (typeof val !== 'string') throw new Error()
}

const x = {
  string: () => ({
    parse(arg: unknown): string {
      isString(arg)
      return arg
    }
  })
}

let a: unknown = 'asd' // a: unknown

x.string().parse(a) // returns: 'asd'

a // a:unknown

Why is it not working?
When using the isString function directly, it does change the type.

asserts only works for that particular scope. It does not bleed into the outer scope or context it was called in.

What you're doing isn't an assertion function (that is, x has no assertion function behavior from the outside). If control flow anlysis could propagate out of functions automatically, then you wouldn't even need an assertion function.  @mocha is right. Does  this fully address your question? If so, one of us will write an answer. If not, what's missing?

@mochaccino so there is no way to make it work?

parse() returns a string, right? Then no, there's no way to make it "work" while keeping that behavior; see microsoft/TypeScript#40562.

so there is no way to make x to have assertion behavior to a? I want to make that if a is really a string, it will change its type to string. Otherwise it will throw an error. @jcalz

I feel like I've already answered this, but I'll try again. Do you need parse() to return a string? If so, then this is currently impossible. If you are okay with it not returning anything, then you can technically do it, but with so many type annotations that it's not worth it, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question or not? (pls don't ask again if there is no way to do it unless you add more information, otherwise we're just going to be repeating the same things over and over and over)

Thanks to the playground I was able to understand it, thanks for the help and sorry for the inconvenience@jcalz

First: simply calling an assertion function inside another function doesn't turn that outer function into an assertion function itself. Calling an assertion function behaves like any narrowing, which has effects on code inside the same scope but generally does not propagate out of it. It would be very hard or impossible to correctly model what control flow analysis should do across function boundaries; there is a very lengthy GitHub issue at microsoft/TypeScript#9998 where they go over the options, and essentially, TypeScript just gives up. Any narrowing that happens inside a function is lost outside the function.
So if you want your outer function to affect control flow upon being called, you'll have to explicitly make it either a custom type guard function or an assertion function itself (note that this is about to change in TypeScript 5.5 due to microsoft/TypeScript#57465 where "simple" boolean-returning functions will be inferred as custom type guard functions).

But your parse() method cannot be a type guard function (since it doesn't return a boolean that determines whether or not the narrowing should take place) and it cannot be an assertion function because it returns a string.  Assertion functions have to return void. There is a feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#40562 to relax that requirement, but for now you're stuck.
If you're willing to make parse() return void then you technically can make it work, but assertion functions have an annoying requirement that you can only call them if they have an "explicit type annotation" as defined in microsoft/TypeScript#32695. So you'd need to assign x.parse() to its own explicitly annotated variable before you could use it.  Which could look like this:
const x = {
    string: () => ({
        parse(arg: unknown) {
            return isString(arg);
        }
    })
}

let a: unknown = 'asd' // a: unknown

// explicitly annotate as having an assertion method
const xStringRet: { parse(arg: unknown): asserts arg is string; } =
    x.string();

xStringRet.parse(a);
a // a: string

This hardly seems worthwhile. So I'd say that what you're asking for is impossible at worst, and unpleasant at best.
Playground link to code
